# Header row is not repeating in some tables in MS Word through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

my table looks like this where the repeat header row is not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDXUZ.png)

Comment: Can you please create a [reprex]? Also see [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: As written, this is off-topic for this forum. It would be suitable in Super User or Microsoft Answers http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word

Comment: Which of the first three rows is the header row? Did you assign the header row before or after vertically merging cells?